How can my edit suggestion be accepted for consideration when it only removes one duplicated little word?
My attempted edit to an answer removes a small duplicated word but it will not be accepted for consideration because of this stipulation: "Edits must be at least 6 characters; is there something else to improve?"
Further, the regulation states:
"We welcome edits that make the post easier to understand and more valuable for readers. Because community members review edits, please try to make the post substantially better than how you found it, for example, by fixing grammar or adding additional resources and hyperlinks."
None of that applies to removing a four-letter duplicated word! Line 5 had 'again again'. Yet the removal makes the post more valuable for readers, as it is now more accurate and (no doubt) as the OP intended. Only 1 'again' is needed, not saying it again!. But there is nothing else to be done to make the answer better.
Can allowance be made for putting such deletions in as edits, and enabling the intended edit to progress on to joining the editing queue for review? Hope so, otherwise my proof-reading skills will go to waste on here!
Was it a custom to offer a dancer that pleased you anything at all? Like in King Herod’s case

I believe with sufficient reputation you are allowed to make small edits like that (with a warning).
If you have enough reputation to make edits without review, you could make a larger edit, then make a second edit deleting the larger stuff.
If you are under both those thresholds, I suppose you could make your small edit, and then under it add something like

extra characters to get around the limit. Reviewers, please modify the edit to remove this notice.

I can't guarantee that reviewers will appreciate being given more work like that though.

Those are all the hacky ways to get around the issue. However, the limit is in there for a reason. Edits to posts bump the entire question on the site's active question list, which can cause users who like to browse the site via that list to expend a lot of energy looking over essentially unchanged old content. In one extreme case we had earlier this week, a user deleting their profile (thus changing the user name on a post of theirs) touched off a comment storm on a 5 year old answer that I was forced to get involved in. If a post needs an edit, it needs an edit (and we appreciate the help!), but philosophically, we should avoid trivial edits here.
Given that, following are the Right™ ways to get around the problem:

Raise your reputation on the site, through positive participation (asking good questions and posting good answers).

Find more improvements to the post to make. Its honestly very rare that I ever go in to edit a post, and find only a single misspelling that needs to be fixed and nothing at all else that could or should be improved.


For example, in the given post linked in this question, I'm seeing the following other improvement opportunities:

It references a Bible verse. It would be really helpful to people analyzing the question to have that hyperlinked to a source like Bible Gateway, so they can easily go read more context from the original work, or perhaps to the Wikipedia page for that Bible section for more in-depth analysis. Adding a hyperlink should easily get you over the edit triviality limit.

It doesn't mention what translation was used. The Bible wasn't written in English.

It included a "quote", but didn't actually bother to use the post quotation gadget (the button at the top of the edit box that looks like a pair of backquotes).

Its completely untagged! That needs to be fixed.

"Custom" in the title probably needs to be changed to "Customary".

The "pleased you" phrasing in the title is awkward and euphemistic-looking (it makes it sound like King Herod was getting a lap dance!). That should be rephrased.



Thanks, T.ED. but a tiny typo does not call for all that palaver re. that one answer I attempted to edit! It wasn't the Q that I was out to tweak. Could there not be an exemption for fixing typographical errors (either in Qs or As)?

@Anne - Ah, well if the link in this question wasn't actually to the post you attempted to edit, then I'd (ironically?) suggest editing the question to fix that. If you wanted to edit an answer, try clicking the "share" button under the answer to get a link to the answer. If you wanted to edit your own comment, the 2 edit trick I mentioned above is your friend.

Apologies - I should have made it clear it was one of the answers I was trying to correct. I've said that at the outset now. I'm not speaking of any comments as I didn't make any, but I will do so now, to the answerer, who can correct his own typo. Thanks.

@Anne - Oh yeah. I should also apologize for not thinking to add "Post a comment with the small tweak you think is needed." as an option.  Note that if a poster makes an edit that completely addresses your comment, its considered good form to delete your comment.

@Anne - Can't help but notice that the first two bullets of my suggested changes for the question also apply to the answer you commented on. That would put an editor well over the minimum.
